# Drupal filters are not cacheable

Tags: 7, caching, input-formats

I have a Drupal 7 site with many custom filters. Everything works correctly, but not quick.
It looks as though the filter cache system does not work properly because the cache_filter table is always empty.
There is the [issues](http://drupal.org/node/1084968) in d.o. but it isn't replied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cache is used only when the input format is enabled to use it; this means that none of the input filters that are used by the input format disable the cache.

The code of [check_markup()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/check_markup/7), which the function that is called when an input format needs to be applied to a text, contain the following code.

```
$cache = $cache && !empty($format->cache);
$cache_id = '';
if ($cache) {
  $cache_id = $format->format . ':' . $langcode . ':' . hash('sha256', $text);
  if ($cached = cache_get($cache_id, 'cache_filter')) {
    return $cached->data;
  }
}
```

`$cache` is a parameter passed to the function, and `$format` is the variable containing the value returned by [filter_format_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--filter--filter.module/function/filter_format_load/7); if `$format->cache` is `FALSE`, the filter cache will not be used.

In the case of the body content of a node, the function that is used to sanitize the body content (and the content of other fields) is [_text_sanitize()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--modules--text--text.module/function/_text_sanitize/7), which invokes `check_markup()` without to use the fourth parameter (`$cache`), which by default is `FALSE`. This means that, whatever the filter is set to use the cache or not, the cache will not be used.

```
function _text_sanitize($instance, $langcode, $item, $column) {
  // If the value uses a cacheable text format, text_field_load() precomputes
  // the sanitized string.
  if (isset($item["safe_$column"])) {
    return $item["safe_$column"];
  }
  return $instance['settings']['text_processing'] ? check_markup($item[$column], $item['format'], $langcode) : check_plain($item[$column]);
}
```

This is different from what done by user_comment_view() (the implementation of `hook_comment_view()` that is used to filter out the signature of the user who wrote the comment), which passes the fourth parameter to `check_markup()`, setting it to `TRUE`.

```
function user_comment_view($comment) {
  if (variable_get('user_signatures', 0) && !empty($comment->signature)) {
    // @todo This alters and replaces the original object value, so a
    //   hypothetical process of loading, viewing, and saving will hijack the
    //   stored data. Consider renaming to $comment->signature_safe or similar
    //   here and elsewhere in Drupal 8.
    $comment->signature = check_markup($comment->signature, $comment->signature_format, '', TRUE);
  }
  else {
    $comment->signature = '';
  }
}
```

Comment: This is by design: the rendered fields themselves are cached, so it serves no purpose to cache them in `check_markup()`.

Answer (score 1):

If cache_filter table is empty, but memcache or APC is enable, then it's great ;)

Or as kiamlaluno pointed out, one of your filter disables cache (e.g. PHP filter) so that the whole format that uses that filter is not cacheable.

Comment: I have default format "Filtered HTML" and four filters enabled:  1. Limit allowed HTML tags"
 2. Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. <br> and <p>) 
3. Convert URLs into links 
4. Correct faulty and chopped off HTML **Wich of them filters can disable cache?**

Comment: I was talking about cache because you told "many custom filters". With all the filters you list, that format is cacheable. But there is another reason, that cache_filter is empty because the whole content is cache elsewhere (cache_field for instance). Are you sure that the filter is processed again and again everytime you view your content?

Comment: You are right. Default filters are processed only after cache cleaning. And it's really, content is cached in __cache_field__.  It seems as __cache_filter__ hasn't ever been used. Can you explain me in which cases this table will be used?